# Eclipse crashes when I invoke Android Layout Editor

Tags: android

I'm new to Android & Eclipse. I've downloaded Eclipse and the Android `ADT` and created an ultra-simple `Hello World` app (has only auto-generated `.java` and `.xml` files).

Eclipse *CRASHES* (closes after a very brief pause) when I do the following:

1. In Package Explorer, select `AppName/res/layout/main.xml`
2. Press , or double-click, or 'Open With' then 'Android Layout Editor'

(The app runs OK in the Android emulator)

My configuration is:

> Android Development Tools 0.9.5.v200911191123-20404  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   Eclipse IDE for Java Developers  1.2.2.20100216-1730  epp.package.java
>
> Windows XP

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what's wrong with my configuration?
Any suggestions on what to check? For any non-trivial app development I need to
be able to use the Layout Editor.

More ... I can select `main.xml` and Right-Click and 'Open With' any of: XML Editor,
XML Schema Editor, Text Editor -- with no problem. The problem is limited to Android Layout Editor.

THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem.

I discovered the .log files (under \Android SDK\eclipse-java-galileo ...\eclipse )
These files are apparently created by Eclipse when a fatal exception occurs. Upon examining the latest file I saw

```
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d2521e1, pid=9156, tid=13952
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0_02-b09 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [fontmanager.dll+0x121e1]
```

and when I looked further, found the folder where fontmanager.dll resides.

Deducing that 'fontmanager.dll' was part of the Java runtime, I saw that I'd been using jre1.5.0_02, and, upon checking the Sun site, discovered that it's an outdated file. So I downloaded (from Sun site) and installed the latest version of the Java runtime.

That fixed it! The Android Layout Editor runs without problems.

THANKS to Nathan for his efforts. As it turned out, his suggestion didn't solve this particular problem, but the info he provided will no doubt be useful.

Comment: Thanks man. I wasted many days and finally your answer helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upgrade your jdk version to the latest version. I found most of the cases online is that the jdk5 made the eclipse crashed and they worked out by upgrade to jdk6. I used jdk6 but the problem existed! At last I download the [latest version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html)(jdk7) and the eclipse not crashes any more!

Answer (score 0):

DONT do anything in eclipse while it says "building project" at the bottom right it does this when you load eclipse, and when you run, or add new files.

If you still have the problem, then I cant help you

Answer (score 0):

In case the above answers don't help, this was my resolve:

I had a similar problem where every time I would view the layout editor (even though I was able to see the XML file) Eclipse would crash.  I reinstalled Java, updated Java, and I even reinstalled Eclipse with no avail.  It turns out that it was a corrupt video driver, nvd3dum.dll.  The filename is in the error list.