# Problem with android layout files in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am facing strange problem while developing my android apps in Eclipse. Whenever I click on any `xml` file under `layout` folder eclipse shuts down.If I open any xml file from other location then it works fine.I tried deleting / creating new projet, Eclipse restart, PC restart but no luck.
Here is the log which is generated in Eclipse folder when Eclipse shuts down

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by HotSpot Virtual Machine:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d252e14, pid=3236, tid=332
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.5.0-b64 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [fontmanager.dll+0x12e14]
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00858f68):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=332]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x2500212c

Registers:
EAX=0x25002000, EBX=0x076ac700, ECX=0x0012ddc4, EDX=0x00010014
ESP=0x0012dd2c, EBP=0x0012dd88, ESI=0x00b6e800, EDI=0x00000800
EIP=0x6d252e14, EFLAGS=0x00010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0012dd2c)
0x0012dd2c:   00000000 0012ddb4 6d24e9e4 00b6e800
0x0012dd3c:   076ac700 03ab5fa0 340a6450 00000000
0x0012dd4c:   0012dd4c 340ca05d 0012dd74 340ca440
0x0012dd5c:   00000000 67ea0028 0012dd64 34a45f10
0x0012dd6c:   0012dd88 34a46508 00000000 34a45f60
0x0012dd7c:   0000000c 146e35e0 00c45de0 0012ddc8
0x0012dd8c:   6d2617ec 076ac700 00000001 00000048
0x0012dd9c:   00000048 0012ddb4 00000001 0012ddc4 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d252e14)
0x6d252e04:   ff 15 30 c0 26 6d 83 c4 0c 8b 46 04 85 c0 74 09
0x6d252e14:   66 8b b8 2c 01 00 00 eb 1b 8b 46 08 85 c0 74 09 


Stack: [0x00030000,0x00130000),  sp=0x0012dd2c,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [fontmanager.dll+0x12e14]
C  [fontmanager.dll+0x217ec]
C  [fontmanager.dll+0x21ecc]
j  sun.font.FileFont.getFontMetrics(J)Lsun/font/StrikeMetrics;+0
j  sun.font.FileFontStrike.getFontMetrics()Lsun/font/StrikeMetrics;+16
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.initMatrixAndMetrics()V+28
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(Ljava/awt/Font;Ljava/awt/font/FontRenderContext;)V+62
j  sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.<init>(Ljava/awt/Font;)V+5
j  sun.awt.SunToolkit.getFontMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+44
j  sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.getFontMetrics(Ljava/awt/Font;)Ljava/awt/FontMetrics;+13
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.updateFontObject()V+140
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.setTextSize(Landroid/graphics/Paint;F)V+25
j  android.graphics.Paint.setTextSize(F)V+2
j  android.widget.TextView.setRawTextSize(F)V+17
j  android.widget.TextView.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V+2609
j  android.widget.EditText.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V+4
j  android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;I)V+4
j  android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V+5
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x8168d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd4179]
V  [jvm.dll+0x8155e]
V  [jvm.dll+0xe44fe]
V  [jvm.dll+0x9f405]
C  [java.dll+0x6bee]
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+72
J  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+92
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+269
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+34
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+65
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+5
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/View;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V+139
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Z)Landroid/view/View;+176
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;)Landroid/view/View;+12
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate()Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+292
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/SessionParams;)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+36
j  com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/SessionParams;)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+12
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession()Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+558
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.render()Z+385
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.initColors()V+22
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PreviewIconFactory.getBackgroundColor()Lorg/eclipse/swt/graphics/RGB;+8
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.PaletteControl.reloadPalette(Lcom/android/sdklib/IAndroidTarget;)V+305
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.reloadPalette()V+21
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ConfigListener.onConfigurationChange()V+277
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange()V+17
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.onDescriptorsChanged(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)V+48
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.initUiRootNode(Z)V+99
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.xmlModelChanged(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)V+10
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor$XmlModelStateListener.modelChanged(Lorg/eclipse/wst/sse/core/internal/provisional/IStructuredModel;)V+12
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createTextEditor()V+140
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.createAndroidPages()V+10
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages()V+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages()V+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V+16
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper()Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+321
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart()Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;+27
J  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+233
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+27
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/WorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+8
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run()V+29
j  org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+116
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+59
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+7
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+5
j  org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IFile;ZZ)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+36
j  org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IFile;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+4
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IFile;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+27
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(Ljava/lang/Object;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run([Ljava/lang/Object;)V+59
j  org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/IStructuredSelection;)V+16
j  org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelection;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run()V+5
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelection;Z)V+22
j  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelection;Z)V+9
j  org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/OpenEvent;)V+25
j  org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run()V+8
J  org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable;)V
J  org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable;)V
v  ~RuntimeStub::alignment_frame_return Runtime1 stub
j  org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable;)V+4
j  org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(Lorg/eclipse/jface/viewers/OpenEvent;)V+32
j  org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+31
j  org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+5
j  org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/events/SelectionEvent;)V+38
J  org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents()Z
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z
J  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Lorg/eclipse/jface/window/Window$IExceptionHandler;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;)V
v  ~OSRAdapter
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI()I+393
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+55
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+84
...<more frames>...
```

And it grows to two more pages. Any guess / suggestion ?
**PS :** I will really appreciate if anybody can edit my question as I am not sure what should be exactly asked / mentioned.

Thanks,
Ajinkya.

Comment: I'd suggest re-installing Eclipse and your JDK, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Joseph: After Googling I found that other people also face this problem and its related to JRE version.

Comment: Time to upgrade then. It might be worth letting people know what JRE you're using at the moment and what JRE you got it working with (when you do) just in case anyone else comes across the same problem on SO.

Comment: @Joseph Earl: Ya sure. Just a moment updating my JRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old JRE version was causing this issue. Updated JRE and BOOM :)
[Eclipse crashes when I invoke Android Layout Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345811/eclipse-crashes-when-i-invoke-android-layout-editor)

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me is to right-click the layout file and open is as another type (say text file or another xml format options in there). I used to have these errors on Ant xml files when I worked on them and this shortcut worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. Updating JRE also sounds pretty simple :)